# tox always returns "dictionary changed size during iteration"

Tags: python, tox

I have a fresh install of tox that always returns "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration". Even when running it without parameters. It looks like it's failing when it attempts to import thing from pyparsing. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running tox 3.20.0 on MacOS under Python 3.7.3.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
(py37) thisuser$ tox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/bin/tox", line 5, in <module>
    from tox import cmdline
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .session import cmdline  # isort:skip
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tox/session/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tox.config import INTERRUPT_TIMEOUT, SUICIDE_TIMEOUT, TERMINATE_TIMEOUT, parseconfig
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tox/config/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from packaging import requirements
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 4909, in <module>
    _escapedPunc = Word( _bslash, r"\[]-*.$+^?()~ ", exact=2 ).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t:t[0][1])
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1294, in setParseAction
    self.parseAction = list(map(_trim_arity, list(fns)))
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1076, in _trim_arity
    this_line = extract_stack(limit=2)[-1]
  File "/Users/thisuser/.virtualenvs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1060, in extract_stack
    frame_summary = traceback.extract_stack(limit=-offset+limit-1)[offset]
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 211, in extract_stack
    stack = StackSummary.extract(walk_stack(f), limit=limit)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 363, in extract
    f.line
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 285, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 48, in getlines
    for mod in sys.modules.values():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Maybe show your `tox.ini`?

Comment: This happens with a completely empty tox.ini, or with the minimal tox.ini, with the basic example described on https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/pytest.html#basic-example and with any combination of the parameters I've tried setting. I suspect that the ini isn't responsible.

Comment: (This question came up on my feed again, due to the below answer) -- If it happens with any `tox.ini` then I feel like it is not something that can be answered here on stackoverflow. I'd rather suggest raising an issue on tox's bug tracker (if there is not any ticket open for that issue yet).

Comment: `for mod in sys.modules.values()` is not supposed to be anywhere in the source code of the `linecache` module. Something's up with that.

Comment: [True](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/linecache.py). @RobertRapplean Where did you get this installation of Python from?

Comment: Brew install python3. I'll see fi I get the same results with 3.8.5 or 3.6

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using Mac OS default Python version (3.7.3). I checked the `tox.ini` file, and I saw some references to py36, so I used `pyenv` to switch to Python 3.6.9. This has fixes the `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` error for me, and all tests were successfully triggered.

Comment: Looks like there might be something wrong with macos default's Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I'm using the default interpreter, but I'll check it when I get into work.